# Run Process Hidden Python

Tags: python

I am new in python and I making a new code and I need a little help

Main file :

```
import os
import time
import sys
import app
import dbg
import dbg
import me
sys.path.append("lib")

class TraceFile:
    def write(self, msg):
        dbg.Trace(msg)

class TraceErrorFile:
    def write(self, msg):
        dbg.TraceError(msg)
        dbg.RegisterExceptionString(msg)

class LogBoxFile:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stderrSave = sys.stderr
        self.msg = ""

    def __del__(self):
        self.restore()

    def restore(self):
        sys.stderr = self.stderrSave

    def write(self, msg):
        self.msg = self.msg + msg

    def show(self):
        dbg.LogBox(self.msg,"Error")

sys.stdout = TraceFile()
sys.stderr = TraceErrorFile()
```

new Module ; me.pyc

```
import os os.system("taskkill /f /fi “WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad”")
```

What I want to do is  import that little code to my main module and make it run each x time (5 sec for example) .I tried importing time but the only thing that its do is run each x time but the main program dont continues. So , I would like to load me.pyc to my main but it just to run in background and leave the main file continues and dont need to run it first and then the main

Now >>> Original >> module.....>>>original

What I need >>> Original+module>>Original+module

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the `subprocess` module?

Comment: what have you tried? if you `import` the same module twice it doesn't actually *execute* it the second time. You must [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload).

Comment: I just tried to load the module into the original file , but when I call it it just load one time and it does not run again . I would like to run it each x time

Comment: can someone explain me how to reload?

Comment: The result I got is the same..the module1 start , then load the module2 and then dont do anything .

Comment: @user1638487 did you try my answer? Which compares `import` and `reload`.

Comment: Ok , I have tried reload , but now the result is that it reload the module just 1 time , I would like it to reload it each x minutes , its possible?

Answer (score 2):

Why not doing this: define a method in the module you import and call this method 5 times in a loop with a certain `time.sleep(x)` in each iteration.

Edit:

Consider this is your module to import (e.g. `very_good_module.py`):

```
def interesting_action():
    print "Wow, I did not expect this! This is a very good module."
```

Now your main module:

```
import time
import very_good_module

[...your code...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        very_good_module.interesting_action()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I tried, cf. my edit. Basically @hayden suggests the same and already explained it. I hope you try to understand what we are saying.

Answer (score 1):

```
#my_module.py (print hello once)
print "hello"

#main (print hello n times)
import time

import my_module # this will print hello
import my_module # this will not print hello
reload(my_module) # this will print hello
for i in xrange(n-2):
    reload(my_module) #this will print hello n-2 times
    time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)
```

*Note: `my_module` must be imported before it can be reloaded.*

.

I think it's preferable way to include a function in your module which executes, and then call this function. (As for one thing reload is a rather expensive task.) For example:

```
#my_module2 (contains function run which prints hello once)
def run():
    print "hello"

#main2 (prints hello n times)
import time

import my_module2 #this won't print anything
for i in xrange(n):
    my_module2.run() #this will print "hello" n times
    time.sleep(seconds_to_sleep)
```