# Import a module more times

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Process Hidden Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214326/run-process-hidden-python)

I am new in phyton and I need to write a code for "Python22" :

I have `module1` and `module2` , I would like to load `module2` from `module1`

module 1 :

```
import module2
```

Module2:

```
import os
os.system('taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad')
```

If I open `module1` the process is killed but just one time, what I would like to do is load the `module2` each 2 min(for example)

I tried `time.sleep(2)` but the only way that I think I can do it is by copying the same lines much time, so its not correct.

Thanks for help!

Comment: @moopet: good catch, I was about to hit submit on an answer which was almost identical to Gehrcke's there..

Comment: It's the same guy who is asking :-(

Answer (score 1):

Import only works once. If you want to reload the module, you need to call

```
reload(module2)
```

But that's beside the point - reloading a module is not something you should do regularly. What you *want* to do is put your system call in a function, and then call that.

Module1:

```
import os
import time
def kill_notepad():
    os.system('taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Notepad')
while True:
    kill_notepad()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for help , but I get this :  C:\Python22\Z>C:\Python22\Z\anti.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python22\Z\anti.py", line 5, in ?
    while True:
NameError: name 'True' is not defined